# How to change status bar color ionic 3 app

Tags: ionic-framework

I have been trying to change status bar color in Ionic App with the following method:

```
 import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

 constructor(private statusBar: StatusBar) { }

 this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);

 this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
```

But still the status bar color doesn't change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found the solution after days of searching.
First install

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
npm install --save @ionic-native/status-bar
```

then add the following to the config.xml

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#2873ed" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 4):

### Installation

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/status-bar@4 // @4 for ionic 3
```

### Usage

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

constructor(private statusBar: StatusBar) { }

...

// let status bar overlay webview
this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);

// set status bar to white
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
```

see [ionic 3](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/status-bar/) status bar